# MongoDB- Customzieable log size and growth strategy

Tags: mongodb, logging, size

I have been running MongoDB for some time. There brings about a issue deserved to be paid.

My customzie log strategy like below:
1) Limit a maximum size of 50MB for each log file
2) Limit a total of 7 log files under the specified log path

How can I implement such things in MongoDB?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write a cronjob that checks the size of the log file, and if it is greater than 50MB it sends your mongodb process a SIGUSR1 (signal number 10). This will then rotate the mongodb logs.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it as a valid answer - gotta get those SO points!